# solution to this recursive function questions?

Tags: python, function, recursion

Can anyone solve this recursive funtion problem?

> Write a program that determines all the alphabetic translations of a phone number. If a non- translatable character appears in the input string, it should be passed on as a constant.
>   Input: A Sequence of 7 digits strings, one per line. Terminated by a string of 7 0's.
>
> Sample input:
>
> ```
> borla63
> 0000000
> ```
>
> Sample output:
>
> ```
> borlamd,borlame,borlamf,borland,borlane,borlanf,borlaod,borlaoe,borlaof
> ```

```
    #data5.py
import string
lets=["","","abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqrs","tuv","wxyz"]
def rep(numb,index):
    if index<len(numb) and (numb[index]) not in assi at +"01"
    for letter in lets[int(numb[index])]:
        rep(numb[:index] +letter+numb[index+1:],index+1)
    elif index>= len(numb:
        print(numb)
    else:
        rep(numb,index+1)
while True:
        number=input()
        if number=="0000000":
                     break
                     rep(number,0)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: this question is from a previous contest, I copied down a portion of the solution, but i mis-copied a portion of it, and managed to break the code. Would the community be willing to fix this code for me? note it doesn't produce an output.

Comment: We have no problem with students, but this is not an on-topic question; please take some time to read the material in the help center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: STOP being so damn picky and next time just help people without slamming them!

Comment: No. Nobody has "slammed" or "bullied" you, you have been politely asked to demonstrate some effort. This site has clear standards for what constitutes an acceptable question, and is not a code-writing service; if you have a problem with that, please find a different site.

Comment: Your if statement is wrong.  No : at the end.  this is wrong: not in assi at +"01".  The code below it should be nested.  Be nice @Lilyk27. It works better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the down-votes and the closing votes, since you don't show the slightest effort here. On the other hand, this is a non-trivial problem. I will assume for a second that you are genuinely interested in a solution to this problem and I'll show you how I would write this (without having looked too much at the code you posted).

```
lets=("", "", "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqrs", "tuv", "wxyz")

def trans(pnum, res = ""):           # res is the current result (initially the empty string)
    if not pnum:
        yield res                    # phone number is empty string, so we're done, return res
    else:
        digit = pnum[0]              # get first digit
        try:
            repls = lets[int(digit)] # if it is an integer, get replacements
            if not repls:            # if replacements is an empty string,
                repls = digit        #    fall back to initial digit
        except ValueError:
            repls = digit            # not an integer  - fall back to initial character
        for i in repls:              # for every replacement character
            yield from trans(pnum[1:], res+i) # recursively process the rest of the phone number

for pnum in ["borla63", "h3llo"]:
    print(list(trans(pnum)))
```

which yields

```
['borlamd', 'borlame', 'borlamf', 'borland', 'borlane', 'borlanf', 'borlaod', 'borlaoe', 'borlaof']
['hdllo', 'hello', 'hfllo']
```

Now I don't know how question bans work, but I hope you use your "time-out" to study this code a little bit and then make the appropriate changes to the one above.

Note that this is Python 3.3+, if it matters.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm just a little stressed out for the comp sci team selection test on thursday, so your answer has been a great help!

Comment: @Lilyk27 No problem. I trust that you will be back to SO with better prepared questions later ;-) Good luck with your test!